# Sharepoint: Is there a way to let end-users automate input of certain fields in a form?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, testing

I am working with Sharepoint 2013 to write software issues and I am asking this question to convince management to improve our software issues work process. I have little knowledge about the service but I pick up fast. My question is:

**What is the simplest way to let end-users automate input of certain fields in a form?**

Following is my use scenario:

We are different teams that are required to fill in about 10-15 fields in a long form. For each team only two of the fields require new data to be filled in, which makes it time-consuming and tedious to fill in the other fields.

For when a new software issue is found: The team member that found the issue is required to state in the form the related project and team, who the issue is going to be assigned to etc. This data is always the same for about 8 weeks of time, which is why it would be positive if the end-user could have control and decide what fields that shall have automatic data input. The new data for each software issue is only comments about the issue and the title of the issue.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: By a form you mean a sharepoint list new/edit form?

Comment: Yes, by form I mean a new/edit form in a sharepoint list.

Answer (score 0):

We use generic .ashx handler(s). You can deploy them to the 14 hive under the LAYOUTS folder. We use these to return html snippets and json objects (depends on the design).

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to fill the fields as you want. With the `val()` from [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.formfields.html#.val) it would be easy. Example:

```
$SP().formfields("Category").val("Something");
```